# $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} + [\alpha + \beta\cos{2x}]y=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have trying to solve this differential equation $$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} + [\alpha + \beta\cos{2x}]y=0 $$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real constants.

Now I thought about it for a while and if I substitute $z=\cos^2x$, I get$$4z(1-z)\frac{d^2y}{dz^2} +2(1-2z)\frac{dy}{dz}+ [\alpha + \beta(2z-1)]y=0 $$
Now this is by far the best substitution I could think in this equation but even after during a power series expansion I couldn't proceed much further.

Comment: See Mathieu equation, Hill matrices, perturbation methods,...

Comment: @Lutz my professor advised me to use Fourier Transform to solve it, but I find anything you suggested using Fourier Transformation.

Comment: The Hill matrices are the coefficient matrices that you get when you insert a Fourier series, in real sin-cos form. This is not really a simplification, that none such exists is "proved" by the fact that the solution family is named. It is noted that these functions are hard to approximate (numerical integration counts as expensive).

Comment: I just saw, your equation is not really linear. Is that the intention, to have $$x''(y)+[α+β\cos(2x(y))]y=0?$$

Comment: yes it is intentional.

Comment: Then the transformation that you tried is probably wrong, as that seems to be based on $y(x)=u(\cos^2x)$, meaning that $x$ is the free variable that is re-parametrized to $z$, relabeling $u$ to $y$, or using only coordinate variables with implied functional relations, à la $y=v(x)=u(z)$.

Comment: Oh I see.  Any clue on how I should proceed?

Comment: Check your task, check the history of the task, ask your professor if the formulation is correct,... The linear [Mathieu equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function#Explicit_representation_and_computation) has, as said, a well studied Floquet/Fourier series expansion.